# Js functions are not working when added Custom section

Tags: magento2, javascript, phtml, section

When i added a custom section. then other js functions( addtocart functionality and slider) is not working on that specific page/phtml

custom.phtml

```
<div class="od-qtysection"data-bind="scope: 'section'"> 
<div class="od-grid-container">
    <?php foreach ($productCollection as $product):
        $productName = $product->getName();
        $addToCartUrl =  $block->getAddToCart($product);
        ?>
    <div class="od-inner-container">
        <div class="od-card-layout">
            <div class="od-product-normal"><?= $productName ?></div>
            <!--ko foreach: customsection().dealqtydata-->
             <!--ko if: ($data.design_id == <?= $designId ?>)-->
                 <!--ko if: ($data.productId == <?= $product->getId() ?>)-->
            <div class="od-qty">
                <div class="sold-item-qty"><?= /* @noEscape */ __('Sold '); ?><span data-bind="text: $data.soldQty"></span></div>
                <div class="total-items-qty"><?= /* @noEscape */ __('Out of '); ?><span data-bind="text: $data.dealQty"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="od-progress">
                <progress class="soldout" data-bind="value: $data.soldpercent" max="100"></progress>
            </div>
             <!--/ko-->
             <!--/ko-->
           <!--/ko-->            
            <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?= $addToCartUrl; ?>" method="post">
                <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
                <div class="od-cartbtn">
                    <button type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="action tocart primary">
                        <?= /* @noEscape */ __('Add to Cart'); ?>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Vendor_Module/js/productslider" : {
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "section": {
                        "component": "Vendor_Module/js/section"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is my custom  section.js

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function (Component, customerData) {
    'use strict';
     var sections = ['custom_qtysection'];
    customerData.invalidate(sections);
    customerData.reload(sections, true);
    return Component.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            this.customsection = customerData.get('custom_qtysection');
        }
    });
});
```

Atlast my slider js as follows

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'slick'
], function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.od-grid-container').slick({
            infinite: true,
            slidesToShow: 2,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            autoplay: true,
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you check your browser console for errors? Probably there is  JS error which prevents execution of code.

Comment: Yes I checked but no erros in console